# Dashboard icons missing with flexible SSL

Tags: cp-dashboard

We are enabling SSL initially via cloudflare and their free flexible SSL. This works great for the site content, but on the dashboard for craft, if I login, any icons are converted into words.

https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl

I am seeing that the page is serving mixed secure content, but wonder if there is a way to make craft happy with this situation and render the font icon properly?

We will eventually implement a full SSL cert, but this will be in place for a while.

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of a stab in the dark, but have you tried forcing SSL for all CP requests?

http://buildwithcraft.com/help/force-ssl

Ultimately your .htaccess would look something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

 # Force SSL for CP requests
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin/ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
 RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks Alec, this didn't work for us. It transpires is a Firefox only issue. I've seen similar things with IE and Firefox with font file locations. A while ago now, so can't recall exactly what the issue is, but other browsers are fine with https on and the dashboard.

Comment: ahh I see, have you managed to find a solution?

Comment: Hi Alec, sorry for the delay in replying. We haven't switch the HTTPS on yet - certs are fun! But the solution will be to use a non firefox browser. I've come across the issue myself when coding, if memory serves it is something to do with the CSS and the paths to the fonts and the way Firefox likes them to be linked. Relative vs. actual paths etc. I'm not sure, it is a long time since I ran into the issue myself when coding. If it happens when the HTTPS is enabled, I'll post again.